# Ad error: AdError 1009: The VAST response document is empty

Tags: google-app-engine, html5-video, adsense, google-ads-api

I am new to this google video ads experience.
I just spend more than 3 hours, I am not sure of where to even get the required information to configure google ima in my app.

So my question is, how do I get the following credentials correctly?

[Image link for the required credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaqQG.png)

```
vgAdTagUrl  Required. String to the advertisement tag url.
```

I want to be able to play pre roll ads in my app videos.

I tried creating an order in the google ads manager platform, but when ever I test the adtagurl, I get the error

```
Ad error: AdError 1009: The VAST response document is empty.
```

My guess is I am doing everything wrong.

So what are the steps to achieve a correct ad tag url and any necessary credentials to us in my html5 video player?